# when to use new keyword to create objects in android?

Tags: android, object, new-operator

Sometimes objects are initialized in android with methods like ..see code below.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

       or 
getSupportFragmentManager() to get reference to fragment object
```

Like in button
we do sth like this

```
Button button = findviewbyid(R.id.button)..
```

i understand that we have created button in layout and we are referring to that button.

But how to get to know that **when to use builtin function to get object and when not to use new keyword????**

don't say please learn basics of java...blah blah..

**guide me properly** as i understand basics of java.in basic java i have never seen that we are using builtin function to get object..

Answer (score 0):

Let us say that you already created a `TextView` in layout xml and just want to refer to that `TextView` in your java file, then you would be using `findViewById(R.id.textView)` but if you want to dynamically create and display a `TextView`, everytime you press a button then you need to use the *new* keyword to make that possible.